# Trazer dados sem refresh no laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, visual-studio, atualização

Galera, tudo bem?

Não estou conseguindo trazer dados do back para o front sem refresh.... alguem pode me dar sugestões?
Vi algumas perguntas, mas nada bem explicado para o laravel.... estou ficando um pouco chateado com esse framework.
Estou usando Laravel + PHP apenas.

Answer (score -3):

você já tentou usar Jquery?
Exemplo:

Na parte de js da sua pagina :

```
$("#botao).on('click', function(){

       $.ajax({
           url: "{{route('criar.cliente')}}", // nome da rota
            type: 'POST', // metodo de "get, post" etc.
         data:{
          valor: valor, // valor que vc quer enviar para a rota acima
          _token:tokenP // este _token sempre deve esta presente na requisição
          },
      
       
        beforeSend: function () { quando enviar
        console.log("Enviando")
        
        },
        success: function(data) { // quando tiver sucesso o (data) contera as informções do seu Back

                  
         

        },
        error: function(data) {

         // se acontecer erro
        }
      });

   })



 se precisa de ajuda para implementar me da um toque que te ajudo
```